MRI contrast power injectors
A power injector is a pump used in MRI (and other applications) to inject the contrast with a given constant speed.
Is it true that with power injectors 2-3ml of the drug is wasted? For a 30ml dose of contrast agent that's 10%! Why would a pump be designed that way?
https://www.guerbet.com/media/sy3dvt1s/gu01240017_guerbet_optistar_sellsheet_20240403.pdf
Above is an example of a specific model that I was asked to provide.
My question is about MRI contrast power injectors in their generality as opposed to specific models. I am interested in the engineering/designing philosphy wasting 10% of the drug because we don't flush the lines into the examine seem excesssive.
I want an answer "without loss of generality" regarding every and any MRI contrast power injector not just specific models.

how efficient is a device that wastes as much as 10% of the drug? ... that would be 90% or higher ... please edit your post... add details about the pump

@jsotola Is 90% good? I wasn't asking about a percentage (certainly not about the percentage of drug used). I was asking about the "quality", cost-effectiveness of the power injectord.

then don't ask vague, indirect questions

@jsotola Nothing about the truth of a specific statement is vague or indirect. Is X true? Clear, concise and direct.

@jsotola efficient: using resources such as time, materials, or energy well without wasting any: He is a leading proponent of broad changes in the Postal Service to make it more efficient and competitive.. There is a comparison (more efficient) withou asking for a clear cut percentage.

is the waste caused by the pump?

@jsotola The question is if the statement is true. Efficient: working or operating quickly and effectively in an organized way:The city's transport system is one of the most efficient in Europe. I am asking if the statement is true. I couldn't possibly know of the cause of something I am wondering if is true,

If you provide an example of such a pump you will probably get better answers.

Off the top of my head though: if you aren't going to flush the lines into the patient using saline, that's probably 2-3 ml of loss right there.

@Drew Thank you for the edit. And thank you for the comment about flushing the lines into the patient using saline. Please attempt to write a couple of paragraphs for an answer. Is the loss only/mainly due to the "lines", how good is the design with 10% waste?

@Drew What do you mean with provide an example of such a pump? Do you mean find the information and the specifications of a specific model and mention it in my question? I don't know this information and it would be hard (bordeline impossible) to get. I can't really go asking in a hospital for the specification of the pump (probably no one in the hospital at the time I go there knows that information). Maybe I could writte a formal request for the managment of the hospital (they most probably won't even bother). The details of the specific pump are not as important as the waste philosophy.

@GeorgeNtoulos Yes, please provide a model, and ideally a brochure, datasheet or manual. It can probably be found on an internet, or you could make some phone calls. This is basic information that you will need to create informed opinion regarding this question.

@Drew But I am not asking SE a question about a specific model. I am asking about the general philosophy/engineering of MRI power injectors. I couldn't possibly ask the radiologist to tell me what model is their power injector (probably they don't care they don't know). The management of the hospital will label me as crazy for asking what model is their power injector. Hospitals don't post this information on the internet because most people don't care. It can't be found on the internet and I don't understand why is it important I am asking about power injectors in general not a specific model

@jsotola Is the way I editted my question acceptable? I don't want to focus on any specific model but I provided https://www.guerbet.com/media/sy3dvt1s/gu01240017_guerbet_optistar_sellsheet_20240403.pdf

Ok, nobody has taken a crack at this in quite a while so I'll try.
If you look at the injector, it's a very simple design. It's just a mechanism which pushes a syringe. The source of the loss is fairly obvious. The drug is pushed through the IV tube, which would be filled with saline. When the syringe is bottomed out, there will still be a small amount of liquid in the IV tube and luer lock area of the syringe.
It might be possible to use a second syringe full of saline to push that last bit through the IV tube. ..But that's more time to set up, it requires more injector channels, and it's another syringe and fittings in the trash. Unless the drug is extremely expensive it seems most practical to just "waste" a few ml.

Is the small amount of liquid in the IV tube and luer lock area of the syringe 3ml? Why would the mechanism be designed this way? Isn't there any other way?  I am not interested in the medical/nursing practice. I am interested in the mechanism design. Couldn't the engineers design it differently (no or at least less waste without needing to flush the lines)?

How? There is a tube connecting the syringe to the patient. Likely at least 2meters. 3ml seems like a fairly reasonable volume for that. The only way to reduce it would be to use a tube with an extremely fine ID, and that would limit the flow rate.
